# not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-idea-shell-2017.2.pom

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt

I am importing a scala Play application in Intellij Version 2018.1.3 with sbt sources . But the project does not resolve in intellij,

I get this error

```
[error] Error downloading org.jetbrains:sbt-idea-shell;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2017.2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/rhande/.ivy2/local/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-idea-shell-2017.2.pom
```

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Update to latest idea and scala plugin

Comment: I have exact same issue. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2, sbt 1.3.13, scala 2.13.3

Answer (score 0):

What IDE and Scala plugin version do you use? Should be [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-17267#focus=streamItem-27-4033656.0-0) in latest 2020.1.X version.

Comment: I use scala plugin version 2018.1.9, sbt plugin version 1.8.0 and intellij 2018.1.3